# append parent names and ids of textboxes to newly generated ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm able to generate more `textboxes` for user to input variables on click of a link. what i've noticed is when the new row of textboxes are generated, it generates with `name` text and id as `id`. But i want it to have the same names of the original or parent textboxes.

```
<table width="80%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCFF"><strong>4. VECHICLE INFORMATION</strong></td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCFF">&nbsp;</td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCFF">&nbsp;</td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCFF"><div align="right"><a class="add_more" href="#">Add More Vechicles</a></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="more_vechicle">
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="text" name="vechicle_name[]" id="vechicle_name" class="register-input" placeholder="Name of Vechicle" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="text" name="vechicle_type[]" id="vechicle_type" class="register-input" placeholder="Type of Vechicle" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="text" name="vechicle_registration[]" id="vechicle_registration" class="register-input" placeholder="Registration No." /></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="text" name="vechicle_color[]" id="vechicle_color" class="register-input" placeholder="Color of Vechicle" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><div align="center">
      <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Save &amp; Continue" />
    </div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
      $('.add_more').click(function(){
          var id=$(':text').length;
          $('#more_vechicle td').append('<input class="register-input" type="text" id='+id+' name="text'+id+'">');
      });
  });
```

Comment: Are you sure you need IDs? If you're generating the IDs dynamically, you probably don't need them, since other code won't try to access them by ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `.each()` loop to loop over the TDs. Then you can get the first input that's in each TD, clone it, and give it a new ID.

```js
$('.add_more').click(function() {
  $('#more_vechicle td').each(function() {
    var these_inputs = $(this).find(".register-input");
    var id = these_inputs.length;
    var new_input = these_inputs.first().clone(true).val('');
    new_input.attr('id', function(i, old_id) {
        return old_id + id;
    });
    $(this).append(new_input);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="80%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCFF"><strong>4. VECHICLE INFORMATION</strong></td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCFF">&nbsp;</td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCFF">&nbsp;</td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCFF"><div align="right"><a class="add_more" href="#">Add More Vechicles</a></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="more_vechicle">
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="text" name="vechicle_name[]" id="vechicle_name" class="register-input" placeholder="Name of Vechicle" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="text" name="vechicle_type[]" id="vechicle_type" class="register-input" placeholder="Type of Vechicle" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="text" name="vechicle_registration[]" id="vechicle_registration" class="register-input" placeholder="Registration No." /></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="text" name="vechicle_color[]" id="vechicle_color" class="register-input" placeholder="Color of Vechicle" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><div align="center">
      <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Save &amp; Continue" />
    </div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: just texted and when i add values to the first set of rows and i click add more, the values in the first row appears in the new ones and i have to clear

Answer (score 0):

The solution you're looking for is jquery's clone() function (http://api.jquery.com/clone/). Just clone `#more_vehicle` and insert it before the continue button.

```
$('.add_more').click(function() {
    $('#more_vechicle').clone()
      .attr('id', null) /* removing id attribute for the cloned
        * tr so there is only one elemnt with that id
        */
      .insertBefore('#append_anchor');
```

Be aware that the default behavior of clone() is to not copy event handler from the parent element.
I'd also suggest to make sure every car gets it's own tr. See the following fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/jcvnos9w/